# How to check if the next td in a tr empty or not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table that has 3 columns. In the first column I have a button and I want to check if the second column has a div of not. I am not trying to do this using jQuery.

This is my html

```
<table class="customFiltersTable" id="customFiltersTable" width="100%" style="background-color: #75A1D0; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px">
   <tbody>


   </tbody>
</table>
```

The (dropdown menu) button is generated dynamically inside the 1st column. Here is the script

```
//create a tr and 3 td inside it then append tr
var fType1 = $('<tr class="rowTableFilters" id="rowFilters'+filtersRow+'" name="rowFilters'+filtersRow+'"><td class="colFilters" id="colFilters'+column1+'" name="colFilters'+column1+'" width="480px" align="center" columnNum="'+column1+'"></td><td class="colFilters" id="colFilters'+column2+'" name="colFilters'+column2+'" width="480px" align="center" columnNum="'+column2+'"></td><td class="delButton" id="delButton" name="delButton" width="40px" align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="deleteFilter'+filtersRow+'" name="deleteFilter'+filtersRow+'" style="float: right;">Del</button></td></tr>');
$("#customFiltersTable").append(fType1);

// create the dropdown menu button in the 1st column along with the list (li)
var fType = $('<div class="btn-group" style="padding: 5px; width: 70%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 100%;">Select Filter <span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%" data-userid="'+(intIdFilters-2)+'" id="filUl'+(intIdFilters-2)+'" currData-value="-1"></ul></div>');
$("#colFilters"+(intIdFilters-2)).append(fType);
$("#filUl"+(intIdFilters-2)).append(li); // li is list already generated.
```

so the if statement I am using (which not working) is this

```
$('#customFiltersTable').on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function () {
if($(this).closest('td').next('td').find('div').length){
...
}
});
```

Any idea please?

Comment: what is `this` referring to in this context?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh sorry!! a edited the if statement.

Comment: it should work... can you share a generated html sample... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3kd24/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Your code looks good. Try removing the 'td' in the next() function.

```
    var $td = $(this).closest('td').next();
    if ($td.find('div').length > 0) { //div exists }
```

Comment: "this" actually means the '.dropdown-menu li a' inside the first td. I want to check if there is another td in the same tr? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use jQuery's [**`has()`**](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method to achieve this:

```
if($(this).closest('td').next('td').has("div")) {
  // It contains a <div> element
} else {
  // It doesn't contain a <div> element
}
```